# A morning appointment

Tags: riddle

> A morning appointment that you rarely miss,
>
> You give me a bath then a passionate kiss.
>
> I'll sit around all afternoon,
>
> But I'm not worried - I'll see you soon.

Comment: A pet dog (or other species)?

Comment: More downvotes with no explanation. Great for us new guys who just want to learn.

Comment: @bg6471 I know... It wasn't meant to be a hard riddle, and I certainly didn't think it was downvote worthy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would guess you are

> A toothbrush

A morning appointment that you rarely miss,

> Brush in the morning

You give me a bath then a passionate kiss

> Run under water then Deep in your mouth

I'll sit around all afternoon

> Not often used in the afternoon

But I'm not worried - I'll see you soon

> But will be used again later in the day

Comment: Correct! Well done.